# Bash recursive function using while loop

Tags: bash, recursion, while-loop

I have a function called func1. When passed an argument it will generate a list of items. I need each of these items to be passed as argument to func1 and so on until there is no more to pass. Ex.

```
func1 <arg>  | while read item
do
   func1 item | while read item1
   do
     func1 item1 <--- how to do this recursion?
   done
done
```

Just need some implementation ideas. Thank you

Comment: start from the base/halting case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this somewhat contrived [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean demonstration program:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

shopt -s dotglob nullglob

# Print the paths to the tree of directories rooted at the given directory
function dirtree
{
    local -r dir=$1

    printf '%s\n' "$dir"
    local entry subdir
    for entry in "$dir"/*; do
        [[ -L $entry ]] && continue
        [[ -d $entry ]] && printf '%s\0' "$entry"
    done \
        |   while IFS= read -r -d '' subdir; do
                dirtree "$subdir"
            done

    return 0
}

dirtree ~
```

- `shopt -s` sets some Bash configurations:

  - `dotglob` enables globs to match files and directories that begin with `.`.
  - `nullglob` makes globs expand to nothing when nothing matches (otherwise they expand to the glob pattern itself, which is almost never useful in programs).
- There's no explicit handling of [base cases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)#Base_case) because when descending a directory structure you are guaranteed to eventually reach a directory that has no subdirectories.  Symlinks can cause cycle in directory structures, so the `[[ -L $entry ]] && continue` line is in the code to stop symlinks being followed.

The function is contrived because the `while` loop and pipeline are unnecessary.  A cleaner, simpler, and more efficient alternative is:

```
# Print the paths to the tree of directories rooted at the given directory
function dirtree2
{
    local -r dir=$1

    printf '%s\n' "$dir"
    local entry
    for entry in "$dir"/*; do
        [[ -L $entry ]] && continue
        [[ -d $entry ]] && dirtree2 "$entry"
    done

    return 0
}
```